# ReactJS internationalization

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, internationalization, multilingual

I am looking into possible solution to deploy reactJS application with internalization feature. I have been looking at 18n, i18next, react-i18next, react-intl. But need an solution to maintain translation files out of the code repository and maintain it separately for the client to provide business to modify the content without deployments.

Comment: You need to pull in the translations from outside the web app, hence use some kind of external service that can deliver the translations as JSON or any other appropriate format. There are lot of third party services around to localize the content. You can then use i18next, react-i18next, react-intl to handle the translations in the web app.

Answer (score 0):

`i18n` supports adding resource bundles after init using [addResourceBundle](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#add-after-init) function:

```
i18n.addResourceBundle("en", "translations", {
    "Welcome to React":
      "Welcome to React and react-i18next, thanks for waiting 5 seconds"
});
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-add-resource-bundle-5trrk?file=/src/i18n.js) for a live working example usage of `addResourceBundle` function 5 seconds after initialization.

Alternatively, you can also use other [lazy loading functions](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations) that are supported by `i18n`.